limited trade execution using using backtesting.py library
My goal is to backtest data where you provide buy/sell dates and closing prices to backtest module in order to backtest data from one source csv (instead of having 3 separate files such as price data, buy signals and sell signals)
I am not sure why not all of the trades execute here. Currently, my trades are being capped at 5? unsure why I cant get more to execute.
Tried setting hedge to true, exclusive orders to false in order to allow for overlapping trades. I set up checking for dates to make sure they werent on holiday. I'm stuck here with trades being capped at 5.
import pandas as pd
from backtesting import Backtest as OriginalBacktest, Strategy
from io import StringIO
import numpy as np
from pandas.tseries.holiday import USFederalHolidayCalendar

# Updated CSV data as a string for buy/sell dates and closing prices
csv_data = """
Buy Dates,Sell Dates,Buy Close,Sell Close
2010-01-15,2010-03-20,120.45,130.23
2011-02-25,2011-05-10,125.67,135.89
2012-08-21,2013-07-22,130.54,140.67
2014-05-23,2014-08-28,135.78,145.34
2015-09-10,2016-01-12,140.23,150.56
2017-02-15,2017-06-18,145.45,155.78
2013-04-18,2014-08-28,135.78,145.34
2015-09-10,2016-01-12,140.23,150.56
2017-02-15,2017-06-18,145.45,155.78
"""

# Read the CSV data from the string
data = pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv_data), parse_dates=['Buy Dates', 'Sell Dates'])

# Adjust for weekends and holidays
cal = USFederalHolidayCalendar()
holidays = cal.holidays(start=data['Buy Dates'].min(), end=data['Sell Dates'].max())

def adjust_date(date):
    while date in holidays or date.weekday() > 4:
        date += pd.Timedelta(days=1)
    return date

data['Buy Dates'] = data['Buy Dates'].apply(adjust_date)
data['Sell Dates'] = data['Sell Dates'].apply(adjust_date)

# Create a DataFrame to simulate stock data for backtesting
date_range = pd.date_range(start=data['Buy Dates'].min(), end=data['Sell Dates'].max(), freq='B')
stock_data = pd.DataFrame(index=date_range, columns=['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume'])
stock_data['Close'] = stock_data.index.map(lambda x: data['Buy Close'][data['Buy Dates'] <= x].max() if not data[data['Buy Dates'] <= x].empty else None)
stock_data.ffill(inplace=True)
stock_data.bfill(inplace=True)
stock_data['Open'] = stock_data['Close']
stock_data['High'] = stock_data['Close']
stock_data['Low'] = stock_data['Close']
stock_data['Volume'] = 1000  # Arbitrary volume

# Define the LinkedTrade strategy
class LinkedTrade(Strategy):
    def init(self):
        self.buy_dates = set(data['Buy Dates'])
        self.sell_dates = dict(zip(data['Buy Dates'], data['Sell Dates']))

    def next(self):
        current_date = self.data.index[-1]

        if current_date in self.buy_dates:
            if self.hedging or not self.position.is_long:
                if self.exclusive_orders and self.position:
                    self.position.close()
                self.buy()
        elif current_date in self.sell_dates.values():
            if self.position.is_long:
                self.position.close()

# Define the custom Backtest class
class Backtest(OriginalBacktest):
    def __init__(self, data, strategy, *, cash=10000, commission=0.0, margin=1.0, trade_on_close=False, hedging=True, exclusive_orders=False):
        self.hedging = hedging
        self.exclusive_orders = exclusive_orders
        strategy.hedging = hedging
        strategy.exclusive_orders = exclusive_orders
        super().__init__(data, strategy, cash=cash, commission=commission, margin=margin, trade_on_close=trade_on_close)

# Initialize the Backtest instance
bt = Backtest(stock_data, LinkedTrade, cash=10_000, commission=.002, hedging=True, exclusive_orders=False)

# Run the backtest
stats = bt.run()
print(stats)

# Plot the results
bt.plot()

# Save individual trade data to CSV with linked buy/sell dates
trades = stats['_trades']

# Map the EntryTime and ExitTime to the linked buy/sell dates
trades['Linked Buy Date'] = trades['EntryTime'].map(lambda x: data[data['Buy Dates'] == x]['Buy Dates'].values[0] if not data[data['Buy Dates'] == x].empty else None)
trades['Linked Sell Date'] = trades['ExitTime'].map(lambda x: data[data['Sell Dates'] == x]['Sell Dates'].values[0] if not data[data['Sell Dates'] == x].empty else None)

# Save the trades to a CSV file
trades.to_csv('linked_trades.csv')

